# Is there i2p gateway?

Tags: i2p

Is there gateway to sites *.i2p of [The Invisible Internet Project](http://geti2pj2fl72u4m2.onion/en/) ?

E.g. There is gateway to Freenet ( [KeyUtils 0.5.3 v5020 (5020)](https://github.com/saces/KeyUtils/) ): http://2vlqpcqpjlhmd5r2.onion

http://2vlqpcqpjlhmd5r2.onion/freenet:USK@Isel-izgllc8sr~1reXQJz1LNGLIY-voOnLWWOyagYQ,xWfr4py0YZqAQSI-BX7bolDe-kI3DW~i9xHCHd-Bu9k,AQACAAE/linkageddon/1011/

Or gateways to onion sites from www: [tor2web.org](http://tor2web.org/), [onion.to](https://onion.to/), [onion.lu](https://onion.lu)

Comment: You mean like adapters from one anonymity network to another? Not a clue, but it's an interesting idea.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use several I2P eepsites from the 'normal' internet and so also through Tor. Several people run so-called inproxies. There are/were:

- http://i2p.to
- http://i2p.in
- http://i2p.us

At the moment only the last works. Just append `.us` (or `.in`, `.to` when the other two are back online) to the I2P url. So if you want to reach zzz's eepsite enter http://zzz.i2p.us. You can do this with or without Tor.

As you found out here are some other sites:

- http://stats.i2p.us/
- http://planet.i2p.us/

Comment: Could you extend you answer with examples, better with kind of directory of sites inside i2p network.

Comment: None of these are working as of July, 2019.

Answer (score 0):

## Add [**`.xyz`**](http://i2p.xyz) after the `.i2p` part. (Works as of 2018.)

E.g.: http://identiguy.i2p.xyz/ (That’s a list of eepsites, with reachability status.)

Some sites don’t work via the proxy;  e.g. http://i2pforum.i2p.xyz/:

> 403 Denied
>
> Inproxy access denied. You must run I2P to access this site.

Error messages can differ.  The displayed page may not even explicitly state that there was an error (e.g. http://stats.i2p.xyz/cgi-bin/dashboard.cgi):

> Welcome to nginx on Debian!
>
> If you see this page, the nginx web server is successfully installed and working on Debian. Further configuration is required. […]

For comparison, the same page accessed from within the network just now:

[image]

Comment: Not working as of July, 2019.